# How to get Complete (Both Sent and Received) Direct messages from Twitter api in single request?

Tags: iphone, twitter

Now i am able to get "Received Direct messages" from [twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/direct_messages) and "Sent Direct messages" from [twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/direct_messages/sent).

But i saw an iPhone application [Seesmic](http://seesmic.com/products/iphone) where direct messages showing as original twitter messages page ([Messages](https://twitter.com/#!/messages)). In that iPhone application they showing both sent and received messages in single page.

I could do this by calling both webservices (http://api.twitter.com/version/direct_messages/sent.json,http://api.twitter.com/version/direct_messages.json) and merging both responses and showing it like original twitter inbox (means showing messages to each user as a separate page).

There are only four methods in [Twitter Direct Messages](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/direct_messages#)

I want to know any other way of getting complete "Direct messages" from twitter in a single request.Is Streaming api is capable of that. There is no enough support in web for streaming api. Please answer me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, I have implemented post twitter direct messages using, https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages/new.json api it works perfect, but now I want to get direct messages from my twitter account , I am doing this by using, https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json?count=1&page=1 api but got error 401, can please anyone explain me how to get twitter direct messages. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single API method that provides this. You will have to make two requests and merge them locally. You could use the [User Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/user_streams) API but the streaming API does not provide any historical data. You would start with no DMs and slowly build up a local cache as DMs are sent/received by the user.